# this.props of reactjs is mutating when the props are extended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am trying to extend the props using _.extend method of lodash and assign it to a new variable. But this is changing the value of this.props

```
var Component = React.createClass({
   render: function () {
      var newProps = _.extend(this.props, {b: 2, c: 3});
      console.log(this.props, newProps);
      return <div> hello world </div>
   }
});

React.render(<Component a={1} b={2} />, document.body);
```

In above example, {a: 1, b: 2: c: 3} is printed into console for both this.props and newProps

But expected values are: this.props = {a: 1, b: 2} and newProps = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_.extend modifies the first argument, and returns it.  To avoid mutations you should pass an empty or defaults object as the first argument.

```
var newProps = _.extend({}, this.props, {b: 2, c: 3});
```

I recommend using the normal name _.assign (extend is an alias).  It's more clear what it does, and matches es6's Object.assign.